# Как сохранить полученные данные в json файл во vue?

Tags: django, json, vue.js

У меня из djаngo во vuejs приходят данные, которые нужно из фронта сохранить в json-файл. Как можно это сделать?
Пробовала с

```
                let data = JSON.stringify(res.data);
                console.log(">>> ExerciseData_data", data);
                var fs = require('browserify-fs');
                fs.writeFile("thing.json", data);
```

но приходит ошибка такая fs.writeFile is not a function. Как можно по другому сохранить в файл данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = JSON.stringify(res.data)
var file = new Blob([data], {type: "application/json"});
var a = document.createElement("a"),
url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
a.href = url;
a.download = "thing.json";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
}, 0);
```

Comment: Благодарю! Работает!